# Many to many with extra fields

Tags: mongodb, database

Let's say I'm making a shopping website, and I need to manage a shopping cart.
In a relational database to store my cart along with items and quantity I'd something like that:

```
+-------------+        +-------------+        +-------------+ 
|   Item      |        |   ItemLine  |        |    Cart     |
+-------------+        +-------------+        +-------------+ 
| id          |        | id          |        | id          |
| name        |--------| item_id     |--------| user_id     |
| price       | 1    * | cart_id     | *    1 | price       |
|             |        | quantity    |        |             |
+-------------+        +-------------+        +-------------+
```

Now I don't have a relational database, instead I'm using MongoDB, and I can't find a good way to do that.

Is there any "right" way to implement that in MongoDB?

Is it possible to save the quantity along with a reference in a list of references? And if it is, would it be a good way to implement that?

Comment: Isn't it one to many? One cart has many items. Each item in it has quantity.

Comment: No cause many items can be in many carts. So I have to have a table to link them, and in this table I add the quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mongodb design following will be more suitable for your scenario

#### Item

```
    {
      _id :"...",
      name : "...",
      price : "....",
      itemLine : [{
                    cart_id : "...",
                    quantity : 10

                   },

                   {
                     cart_id : "...",
                     quantity : "...."

                  }]
    }
```

#### Cart

```
  {
    _id : "..",
    user_id : "...",
    price : "..."

   }
```

**Note:**

1. `itemLine` is embedded document which consists of only two fields, It can    be easily updated since it is one-level array.
2. Most of the quantity can be incremented using $inc, based on the cart_id. Performance will be good.

Mongodb(No joins), So try avoid many relationships.

Answer (score 1):

A field can be type of `array`. I would consider something like

```js
module.exports = new Schema({
    id: Number, //product id
    name: String,
    image: String, 
    ...etc etc
}, { collection: 'Products' });

var PurchasedItem = new Schema({
    id: Number, //id of product
    quantity: Number
});

module.exports = new Schema({
    id: Number, //cart id
    items: [PurchasedItem] 
}, { collection: 'Cart' });
```